# Android OkHTTP returning inconsistent String?

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using OkHTTP to simply get text from the body of a url:

```
class DownloadUrl {
    String readUrl(String myUrl) throws IOException,NullPointerException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(myUrl)
            .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        return response.body().string();
    }
}
```

However, I am getting inconsistent String, despite the URL and its contents being same every time. The some returned string leave out blocks of the JSON for example, I should be getting this:

```
"html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
         "id" : "b89943f74e20eafb8959ace996a6f35cd303d5ff",
         "name" : "Circle K",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 400,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114668422179892290420/photos\"\u003eCircle K\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAAdubSCt5u9IrI6bsL91DGLdIm2SMO39SaKGxKKmrj-ygxrCmIjUzG0DwrBgcX56DdpEFRBev29cdA4ljZnIR7lvPlP3jBhHkBxliRkGlAlfkAh9TiQvVuyNNQLnzIcsuEhAsc0Px0hV4mFTZruHRWLh9GhTIePuzk5JxV1QewH3jimkAKIzALw",
               "width" : 400
            }
         ],
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
"html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "1a830f99aab4e7afa143b2c8d03545ea7c1e9432",
         "name" : "McDonald's",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
```

The "photos" part of the JSON is being left on some calls, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The JSON you're getting is not even a valid JSON (unless you've cut it for display reasons). Did you check with other tools (e.g., Postman) if you're getting the correct response every time you call the service?

Comment: I've cut it for display purposes, and each call, it either has the "photos" child or doesn't. I've checked the URL for each call, and all of the url contains "photos."

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Place Search documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResults) (which is the service you're using, I guess), each `result` object may contain:

> `photos[]` — an array of `photo` objects, each containing a reference to an image. **A Place Search will return at most one `photo` object**.

Also, [Google Place Photos documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) reports that:

> The response [...] will contain a `photos[]` field if the place has related photographic content.

That means that in case a specific result has no photos, then `photos` array won't be present at all in the response.

The examples you provided are not referring to the same place: in the first case you're getting a result for "Circle K", while in the second case for "McDonald's". Based on that, the response seems coherent with what the documentation says.

Comment: This one I posted is just for example, but I will look into that and compare

Comment: @Mozy Did you come up with any outcome?

Comment: Sorry for the late update, but each result had the photo array, but okhttp is not returning the entire body for some reason, thank you though.